# Unable to install new version Pnp powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

We have a requirement to extract sharepoint online  site template using PnP Powershell. As part of it, I am installing new version of PnP.powershell in Powershell (7.4) CommandPrompt.
But there is no result after running the command: Install-Module PnP.PowerShell .
Please find below image :
[image]

I have installed Powershell 7.4 to install new version of PnP Powershell, but installation is not happening.

Please help  me with this issue ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Start a fresh terminal and run:
`Import-Module PnP.PowerShell`

Then you can run:
`Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://site.sharepoint.com/`

Let me know if this helps.